# Android room dao generation fails afrer Migrating to ksp from kapt due to TypeAlias

Tags: android, android-room, type-alias, kotlin-symbol-processing

I have migrated from kapt to ksp for my current android project.

All my dao(s) extend a base dao that is defined as a kotlin typealias as follows:-

```
typealias BaseDao<T> = AbstractDao<T, Long>

@Dao
abstract class AbstractDao<TEntity : IEntity<TKey?>, TKey : Any> {

    @Insert
    abstract fun save(obj: TEntity): Long

    @Insert
    abstract fun save(vararg obj: TEntity)

    @Insert
    abstract suspend fun saveAsync(vararg obj: TEntity)

    @Update
    abstract fun update(obj: TEntity)

    @Delete
    abstract fun delete(obj: TEntity)

    @Insert
    abstract suspend fun saveAll(obj: TEntity)
```

when i look at the generated kotlin code for the `XXXXDao_Impl` classes none of them include the `BaseDao` functions, however when i replace the typealias with the actual `AbstractDao` name the room code generations completes fine.

is there any approach i can take to get ksp to support `typealias` or do i have to replace the `typealias` in all my dao's?

i have raised this issue with google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/327643800